# Pie chart plot of multiple columns in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, pie-chart

```
 df>
 commodity China Australia India Thailand   ROW
      <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
    1 Cereals     4.6       8.2   4.4      4.7  78.2
```

I have this df I need to make a pie plot of these variables (excluding the first one)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to reshape your data then you can plot it with ggplot, like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  select(-commodity) %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = names(.)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = value, y = 1, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = "stack") + 
  coord_polar() + 
  theme_void()
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

You can get as fancy as you like by playing with different options:

```
df %>% 
  select(-commodity) %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = names(.)) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = rev(name))) %>%
  mutate(position = cumsum(lag(value, default = 0)) + value/2) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = value, y = 1, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(aes(x = position, y = 1.7, label = name)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = position, y = 1.3, label = value), colour = "white") +
  coord_polar() + 
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  labs(title = "Cereal production, percentage by country of origin") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = -1))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2020-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: brilliant. What if I'd like to add percentages inside?